# Does $\mathsf{ZF} \vdash \mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0} \rightarrow \mathsf{CC}$?

Tags: set-theory

As the title states, I'm interested in knowing whether the existence of an infinitely enumerable subset in every infinite set (i.e., that for every infinite $X$, there exists some $Y \subset X$ equipotent with $\omega$), which we may term $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$, and which is clearly equivalent to the assertion that a set is Dedekind-finite iff finite, implies countable choice $\mathsf{CC}$.

I have managed to figure out the proof to $\mathsf{ZF} \vdash \mathsf{CC} \rightarrow \mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$, and I'm interested in knowing whether the inverse holds and both propositions are actually equivalent. The search for such equivalence is clearly guided by the equivalence between choice and well-ordering (i.e., $\mathsf{ZF} \vdash \mathsf{C} \leftrightarrow \mathsf{WO}$), and $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$ seeming like the natural restriction to $\mathsf{WO}$ given the restriction from $\mathsf{C}$ to $\mathsf{CC}$, but I'm not fully sure whether it really does hold.

Intuitively, it might perfectly well be the case that it does not hold, as $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$ would just guarantee the existence of *some* infinitely enumerable subset of $\bigcup X$ provided a countable family of sets $X$ with $\emptyset \notin X$. It might very well be that the infinitely enumerable set that is "produced" consists solely of elements found within the very first set of $X$, with all other elements of elements of $X$ being left out and thus unable to be placed into a well-ordering relation (and clearly one cannot "choose" between each of the existing well-orderable infinitely enumerable sets of each set in $X$ as that would necessitate $\mathsf{CC}$ already).

Hence I am left with the suspicion that it might not actually be the case that the inverse holds. I would like to know whether my suspicion is well-founded or whether there is in fact a way to prove the inverse. If so, I would appreciate if such a way were not fully "spoiled" (I'm just trying to figure out whether my efforts are in vain or not).

Many thanks in advance to any and all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result that you're trying to prove is false (see Jech's AC book theorem 8.6).

On the positive side, $\sf WO_{\aleph_0}$ does imply countable choice for families of finite sets, so you may be interested in trying to prove that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you, as always, for the answer :) I'll try thinking of a way to prove that latter statement, although I must admit I still am attempting how to go about it as the same issue I talked about before arises: namely, the infinitely enumerable subset of the union of all these finite sets could itself be missing all elements from one of these particular sets. Even if they are all finite, clearly if, say, one set contains only a single element, I can still select all other elements and should form an infinitely enumerable set...

Comment: @Sho As a hint, note that it suffices to show you can make a choice from infinitely many (but not necessarily all) of the sets. (To see this is equivalent, apply this seemingly weaker principle to the sequence of partial products $B_n = \prod_{i=0}^n A_i$.)

Comment: Sorry for the wait! Hadn't had much time to work on stuff, but I think I've figured out the proof more or less? Let $(X_n)_\omega$ be a denumerable family of finite, nonempty sets. We consider the also denumerable family $(Y_n)\omega$, with $Y_n = \varpi_nX_j$, defining here $\varpi$ as a sort of "unordered Cartesian product" (i.e., $\varpi_\alpha X_\beta = \{\{x_0, \dots, x_\alpha\} \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup_{\beta \leq \alpha} X_\beta) : \{x_0, \dots, x_\alpha\} \cap X_\beta \neq \emptyset \text{ for every $\beta \leq \alpha$}\}$). According to $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$, ...

Comment: there exists some infinitely denumerable $Z \subset \bigcup_{n<\omega} Y_n$. One can see quite easily that $\bigcup Z \cap X_n \neq \emptyset$, for every $n$. A quick sketch for why this is so might go like this: Suppose there were some $X_j$ for which $\bigcup Z \cap X_j = \emptyset$. Since $\{x_i\}_{i \leq n} \cap X_j \neq \emptyset$ for every $\{x_i\}_{i\leq n} \in Y_{n \geq j}$, no $Y_{n \geq j}$ is such that $Y_{n \geq j} \cap Z \neq \emptyset$ (otherwise, i.e., if there were some such $\{x_i\}_{i \leq n} \in Y_{n \geq j}$ in $Z$, then $\bigcup Z$ would contain...

Comment: $x_j \in \{x_i\}_{i \leq n}$). Thus, $Z$ can only possess elements from $(Y_n)_{n < j}$. But, insofar as each $X_n$ is finite, so is every $Y_n$ also finite (specifically, if $X_0, \dots, X_j$ each contain $n_0, \dots, n_j$ resp., then $Y_j$ contains $< C(\sum_{i \leq j}n_i, j)$ elements). But then $Z$ cannot be infinitely denumerable. Hence, it must be that $\bigcup Z \cap X_j \neq \emptyset$. We have then that $Z_0 = \bigcup Z$ is infinitely denumerable (hence well-orderable), and that $Z_0 \cap X_n \neq \emptyset$ for every $n$ (i.e., it contains at least one...

Comment: element from each $X_n$). We consider then some well-ordering $<_{Z_0}$ of $Z_0$. We also observe that the set $\{x \in Z_0 : x \in X_n\}$ is never empty no matter the $n$, hence possesses a $<_{Z_0}$-minimal element $m_n$. As this $m_n$ always exists and is unique, we can explicitly define a function $f \in {\bigcup \mathrm{ran}((X_n)_\omega)}^{\mathrm{ran}((X_n)_\omega)}$ by $f(X_n) = m_n$, for each $n < \omega$. $\square$ @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @Sho I don't have time to go through this, sorry. Here's the proof I know:  Let $Y_n = \prod_{i\le n} X_i.$ Let $f:\omega\to \bigcup_n Y_n$ be injective. Then since each $Y_n$ is finite there must be infinitely many $n$ such that $Y_n\cap \operatorname{ran}(f)\ne \emptyset.$ Given $i,$ take the least $k$ such $f(k)\in Y_n$ for some $n>i$ and choose the $i$-th component of $f(k).$

Comment: No issues whatsoever :) Thanks for the time and for the proof! I think mine works too but it's made harder by the fact I don't use Cartesian products... @spaceisdarkgreen